How to test for performance regression?
I am working on a refactor on a certain package (I can give details if asked). The package involves a clever lazy evaluation of a sort of nested sequence of arithmetic operations. If the numerical algorithm is implemented in the naive way you will get quadratic in size timing performance that becomes super slow on realistic problem sizes. With the clever lazy evaluation you get time linear in size performance that always feels snappy on realistic problem sizes.
The refactor I am doing involves re-writing the code the implements this clever lazy evaluation. During the refactor I have killed the performance a few times with various misunderstandings, oversights, or mistakes. However, I've also gotten the linear-in-time performance with my code.
I would like to add some tests to my unit test suite to ensure I am properly implementing the lazy evaluation to get linear-in-time performance. What is the proper way to do this? Of course I know a variety of ways to time a block of code. My concerns, however, are that I know code will run at different speeds at different times on different machines. Some results I get on my laptop are
For the current code:
### n=10 ###
  10: 0.0001 s
### n=100 ###
  100: 0.0007 s
### n=1000 ###
  1000: 0.0083 s
### n=10000 ###
  10000: 0.0689 s
### n=100000 ###
  100000: 0.6865 s

For my refactor:
### n=10 ###
  10: 0.0002 s
### n=100 ###
  100: 0.0015 s
### n=1000 ###
  1000: 0.0153 s
### n=10000 ###
  10000: 0.1694 s
### n=100000 ###
  100000: 1.4850 s

So we see that both the old code and the new code are giving linear-in-size performance, but my code is a factor of 2-3 slower. Whether this constant slowdown is acceptable or not still needs to be discussed by me and the other developers.
But anyways, the question is how should I write the benchmarking tests? Should I run each of these timing tests in my unit tests suite and check that the performance is less than M times the timing I get on my laptop? M times the timing that I get on the github CI servers? I don't know if the performance on those servers changes in time. Here M is some number between maybe 1.5 and 5 that is agreed upon by me and my team? Should I fit the T vs. N data to a line and do some regression analysis to see that the curve fits well to a line rather than a quadratic or something else? What are standard techniques to test against performance benchmark regressions?

To catch the actual performance regression (instead of just complexity regression) you will have to run tests over the same, fixed hardware. And software of course. There's no other way. In particular such tests won't be portable. But on the other hand you should be able to test concrete timings results, up to some precision.

Just a thought, but have you considered pytest-benchmark - pytest-benchmark - Comparing past runs

@Kate, yes I essentially ended up going with pytest-benchmark together with codspeed.io. I should post an answer to this effect.

If you just want to make sure the algorithm does not show up quadratic run time behaviour, and you know the basic constant startup time is almost negligible, then you can simply

run the code twice, once with 1000 loops and once with 1000 x 1000 loops.

then compare the two runs - the second time it should not last much longer than 1000 times of the first (maybe with some safety margin like a factor of 2).


That is actually a simple form of the kind of regression analysis you suggested, one which is very easy to implement. Still, you have to be careful not to end up with a brittle test which sometimes fails because your test machine processes sometimes something else in parallel during the test. You should make sure any time is measured as real CPU time, not just wall-clock time, and the parts which are measured should ideally be insulated from any kind of I/O operations or other things which are not part of the core algorithm. If you can, use dedicated hardware for the test.
However ...
This kind of test does not prevent you from decreasing the overall performance of the algorithm up to a point it does not suit you any more. If you introduce a bug which simply makes all your the operations slower by a fixed factor, of lets say, 100, the former test won't tell you this.
To prevent against the latter, you need to define your performance requirements first (lets say, for a 100000 times run), in some absolute durations, and compare the actual running times against these requirements. When doing so, it is a good idea to keep the typical as well as the minimal hardware spec in mind for the machines on which the code will be executed in production (hence, your tested durations may need to be smaller than the ones you want to achieve in production).
Unfortunately, there is no sensible way to compare how your code behaves on the test machine and in production (especially when you expect the production machines to have less available CPU power than the test machines), except trying it out on different hardware and gather some numbers empirically. And when you change the testing hardware, you may need to retest and adapt the numbers accordingly.

Perform the whole microbenchrmark dance for every measurement. Warmup of all code paths. Proper state isolation (so that state would be warmed up as well as code paths). Usually people just use timeit, however it is easy to misconfigure a benchmarking library.

The catch all general performance test is to run on the same hardware as live and ramp up a representative-of-live load until the app crashes or tops out.
This catches all sorts of edge cases and the idea is that you will get the same number as you do in live, rather than an absolute measure of time.
If you have a specific algorithm though you could do a static analysis to calculate its big-O time complexity. This is the best measure of an algorithm as its processor independent.
If you want a quick and dirty unit test, run a large set of sample data through old and new algorithms on the same box and compare the times as you have done here.
A single unit test in a build pipeline, calc < 10ms is usually not good enough, as various factors add load to your build box
Running on your dev machine will usually give you much faster times than a live server.

"Running on your dev machine will usually give you much faster times than a live server."  - I would say that depends heavily on the dev machine as well as on the live server.

@DocBrown: As I understand, this is considering the difference between sending the "representation-of-live load" through localhost/127.0.0.1 versus sending it to a separate IP address? Though I guess localhost requests would ignore the possibility of caching/firewall related metrics.

I just meant that on average dev machines are faster than servers. ie If you run your test locally on your alienware dev laptop, but in live its a 1 cpu container on a VM. Don 't be surprised when its slower.

It may not have been clear in the OP, but the question was essentially this: It is pretty clear how to run a speed test, but there are issues having to do with which system you're running on and what the state of that system is during the test. Obviously you can setup some benchmark and try to run it in a consistent environment but is a simple threshold really the way to go for some CI test? It seems like the chance of false negatives or false positives is high which would be annoying.
codspeed.io seems to solve many of these problems. Here you mark tests that you want to performance benchmark with pytest.mark.benchmark and you make some configurations to your CI (in github). Then the CI will run your test and it will run the codspeed benchmarking. From what I can tell the benchmarking creates a virtual machine and the instrumentation measures the number of clock cycles used by the code being benchmarked. This means that CPU intensive neighboring processes will not affect the benchmarking results returned by codspeed.io.
Finally, codspeed keeps a log of all benchmarks run over time in a repo and during PRs will send an alert if a benchmark has a regression (with a configurable performance loss threshold). At first, missing the threshold will cause the CI run to fail, but users can review the results and acknowledge a performance loss to override the failure. To me, this is the best of both worlds. There is CI checking for performance losses, but it is also easy to override if the performance loss is minor. Furthermore, you're not just looking at one number to know if you should override the regression flag or not. You can see the whole history and context of the benchmark within the codebase. You can determine then, with more information, if this regression is really problematic or just a minor fluctuation.
Right now I've configured codspeed to run its benchmarking instrumentation on tests for n=[10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000]. It's not clear yet if running so many tests is necessary since a regression for n=1000 or n=10000 would probably catch the types of code mistakes I want to guard against. The tests also aren't quite free to run. Running this suite of 5 tests takes about 5 minutes compared to a normal CI run that would otherwise be ~1 minutes. Note the tests wall clock run times are only a few seconds, even for n=100000, so the instrumentation is what takes a long time to run.

The above fully solves the absolute benchmarking questions in the OP and it is the solution I've gone forward with.
Regarding complexity benchmarking. For this I set up tests for n=[10, 100, 10000, 100000] and I log the time for each. I then look at the log10 of n/n0 and t/t0 where n0=10 and t0 is the time to run the n=10 test. I check that the ratios of log10(t/t0) and log10(n/n0) are basically equal to within some fudge factor. The logarithm plus the fudge factor give some wiggle room to hopefully avoid false negatives. The fudge factor can also be pretty large while still being able to detect a change from O(n) to e.g. O(n^2). So far this suffices for my purposes. We'll see if I hit  annoying false negatives.

Finally one more note about codspeed. codspeed allows you to generate flame charts showing which subroutines in your program are taking up the most time on the processor. You can also look at the diff on the flamechart. This allows you to easily diagnose slow parts of your code, or changes to your code that caused performance regressions.

Ewan has described good practices for software benchmarking.
I would recommend looking up algorithm engineering for more information on how to do this effectively.

Choose the hardware evaluation platform to be what you would want the software to be executed/run on by its users.
If the software is not executed as "bare metal" software, choose the operating system to run all the software implementations on.
Choose the programming language for all implementations, or select a run-time/virtual environment for all implementations. E.g., choose Java Virtual Machine as a platform, and implement this on Java, Scala, or Clojure. Or, choose the .Net platform as the run-time environment instead. Else, comparing C++ code to Python code to Julia code to OCaml code would yield differences based on whether they are compiled or interpreted, running on a run-time environment or bare metal.
Choose use cases that are realistic to expected use cases, and include boundary cases and unacceptable cases just to see how your (algorithm design and) software implementations would fare. Here, list comprehensions can be used to quickly generate a list of values to test your software. In addition, using use cases from expected applications of your code would allow you to test how well your code will implement in the "real world".
Automated regression testing (combination of automated software testing with regression testing) will help you automatically run the automated regression test suite for performance testing.

